# Selenium nightly regression

Tags: selenium, regression

I'm currently developing a new set of regression tests for an interface using Selenium. I was wondering if it's possible to do a type of batch that runs during the night and which could launch a set of tests (and, i don't know... maybe configure some stuff at the same time). Does anyone know how to do this, or if there is a tool for this that integrates with Selenium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Jenkins/Hudson, that is a continuous integration tool. It has addons as well for Selenium.
More info [here](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins, Hudson, CruiseControl or TeamCity will all be very easy to set up with Selenium.